# pgfplotstable: not printing string type values

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have some data in a csv file I wanted to turn into a table, but pgfplotstable does not print any `string type` values.
All I'm getting is the numbers, but I also need those string values.

The example is from [here](http://texblog.org/tag/pgfplotstable/).

[image: table with stuff missing]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,Surname,Age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    header=has colnames,
    columns={Name,Surname,Age},
    columns/Name/.style={column type={c|},string type},
    columns/Surname/.style={column type={c|},string type}, 
]{data.csv}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you're wrapping the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command in a `tikzpicture` (I'm surprised that there is any output at all). Remove the `tikzpicture`, or put the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command in a `\node`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,Surname,Age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    header=has colnames,
    columns={Name,Surname,Age},
    columns/Name/.style={column type={c|},string type},
    columns/Surname/.style={column type={c|},string type}, 
]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: strange indeed. I guess `\pgfmathprintnumber` also selects a font