# PGFPlots grouped bar chart with error bars providing additional information above, convert point to string in comma for display

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, punctuation

How can I get comma as a decimal separator in my upper axes (the number above the major grid)?

All suggestions to improve the graph are warmly welcomed.

**basic requirement**

- using .csv data with (long) floats and errors
- showing information in grouped pairs (same test body with different clamping setups)
- with error-information (which are sometimes quite big)
- I do not want show every value of every bar, but the mean of every group

I tried and got this, with the problem of the decimal separator being a point mean plot. (Also I do not want any marks or any other things to show up, and the label should be printed in black)

I got the basic setup from [*Manual for Package PGFSPLOTS*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) chapter 8.6 page 551.

**things i tried**

I do not want to change my csv (using a semicolon as a separator and using the comma for decimal separation)
I am using sinuitx. If there's an option to apply this to the meta information it might be a shot. 
I also tried {} around my label data in the .csv, but that did not help.

[image: grouped bar char]

LaTeX-Code:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[11pt, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
            height = 7cm,
            width = 8.5cm,
            ymajorgrids,
            ylabel={The mighty Force in \si{\newton}},
            xlabel={A strong Opponent},
            ymin = 0,
            ymax= 1.75,
            ybar=0pt,
            bar width=12pt,
            enlarge x limits = 0.3,
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            scatter/position=absolute,
            every node near coord/.style={
                    at={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},1.8)},
                    anchor=south,
                },
            bar shift=0pt,
            xtick={0,1,2},
            xticklabels={metal,wood,paper},
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        ]
        \addplot+[bar shift = -12pt]
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table [x=ID, y=A, y error=Aun, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \addplot+[bar shift = +12pt]
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table [x=ID, y=B, y error=Bun, col sep=comma] {data.csv}; % Läd die Daten aus der CSV Datei
        \addplot
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table [x=ID, y=C, y error=Cun, col sep=comma] {data.csv}; % Läd die Daten aus der CSV Datei
        \addplot[only marks]
        plot table [x=ID, col sep=comma, meta=label] {data.csv}; % Läd die Daten aus der CSV Datei
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The content of data.csv:

```
ID,A,Aun,B,Bun,C,Cun,label
0,0.2,0.05,0.3,0.025,0.1,0.03,0.2
1,0.6,0.05,0.4,0.07,0.8,0.045,0.6
2,1.1,0.1,1.3,0.02,1.5,0.06,1.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different things and made therefore multiple mistakes. The following two ones are in addition to the solution important

- Do not use one file where only index and meta is inside
- Do not use `\pgfplotstabletypeset` in `tikzpicture`, [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154034/pgfplotstable-not-printing-string-type-values)

A simple working solution for my problem is changing the file format to *space separated* and that's it.  The option `explicit symbolic` already handles the rest for reading the "new" .dat file correctly ...

[image: barchart with proper meta labels]